# Terminal, double quotation marks create single quotation output

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal

I'm on my Mac Terminal and I don't know why but when I make directory, it's creating a single quotation mark.
It works perfectly fine when there is no space between words

```
> mkdir "some folder"
> ls
'some folder'
> mkdir "amazon"
> ls
'some folder'
amazon
```

What is causing this? and how do i fix it so that i make a directory called `some folder` not `'some folder'`

Also I have a python file that creates a csv using the arguments given. But it's also creating stuff like this:

```
> python somefile.py "vitamin c" "hi" "dog cat"
'"vitamin .csv'
'c".csv'
'hi.csv'
'"dog.csv'
'cat".csv'
```

should be:

```
> python somefile.py "vitamin c" "hi" "dog cat"
vitamin c.csv
hi.csv
dog cat.csv
```

Comment: The follow-up question must be something the python script is doing where it assumes a string does not have spaces or other shell-special characters in it. If the script is short or you can find the suspect bit of code, you can ask a new question about that.

Comment: What if you provide single-quotes like `python somefile.py 'vitamin c' 'hi' 'dog cat'`?

Answer (score 0):

The folder really is named `some folder`, with no quote marks. But the `ls` program is trying to be helpful, to make it obvious that it isn't two directory entries `some` and `folder`, and to make it easier to copy and paste the name into a valid shell command.

One way to stop `ls` from adding the quotes is

```
ls --literal -1
```

The `--literal` means not to add any quote marks, backslashes, etc. The `-1` means to make sure there's one directory entry on each line.

Comment: I sort of edited my question to see if there was other solution. Also is there way to make that `ls --literal -1` command permanent?

Comment: Often people will create shell aliases for their frequently used options to command line tools like `ls`, `ps`, etc. You can even make an alias with the same name as the standard command to "replace" it just in your shell.